# Hibernate 4 explicit polymorphism (annotation) not working?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, polymorphism, hibernate-4.x

I am facing problem with hibernate's explicit polymorphism. I used the polymorphism annotation and set it to explicit, but with get() and collections in mapped classes i always get all subclasses. I see all subclasses with left join in the hibernate "show_sql" output.
What's the problem? Do I understand the documentation wrong? Or is it a bug in hibernate 4? I haven't seen any example with hibernate 4 and polymorphism annotation.

```java
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Node.class, 111); // return subclasses!


@Entity
@Table(name="Nodes")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Polymorphism(type= PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class Node implements Serializable {
    ...
}



@Entity
@Table(name="Persons")
public class Person extends Node {
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Networks")
public class Network extends Node {
}

...and other subclasses...
```

Comment: I created a new project from scratch with fruits as classes. And i had the same problem. Either I did not understand the use, or it is actually an error.

Comment: Do u resolve this issue?

Comment: I could not solve the problem! Sorry! I have no time for solving it, but next month i'll try it again.

Comment: This has to be a bug. Someone should report this.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300157/are-there-other-use-cases-for-polymorphismtype-explicit-than-the-lightweight-p and the questions linked from there?

Comment: In Hibernate 3.2 I use Polymorphism explicit on the base class and works. Peraphs is a bug of Hibernate 4! Oh my god!

Answer (score 5):

Its a common miss understanding, I too had the same doubt once..

**This is what really Happens in explicit polymorphism  .**

> > **polymorphism explicit only applies on root entities and prevent
> >     queries naming a (unmapped) superclass to return mapped sub entities**
>
> In your case, if Entity Class **Nodes** were not mapped and **Persons** were
>   having polymorphism explicit, then **Nodes would not return Persons
>   elements**.

Look at this code..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Nodes")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Node implements Serializable {
    ...
}



@Entity
@Polymorphism(type= PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
@Table(name="Persons")
public class Person extends Node {
}


@Entity
@Polymorphism(type= PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
@Table(name="Networks")
public class Network extends Node {
}
```

Its basically the reverse of what everyone have in there mind.!!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of [PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/PolymorphismType.html) it says:

> EXPLICIT: This entity is retrieved only if explicitly asked.

To hide the subclasses, you will have to annotate the subclasses with EXPLICIT and not the base class.